# How can I run I python script on my ubuntu server (using putty for acces) while still being able to look into other files?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, webhooks, putty

How can I run I python script on my ubuntu server (using putty for acces) while still being able to look into other files?

I'm trying to set up a webhook with learnworlds

Here is my setup:

Ubuntu 23.04 x64 server from vultr.com
URL from namescheap that redirects to the server ip
Within the server, I have a python script called `webhook_server.py` and an empty CSV file.
The CSV file is supposed to be filled when the python script collects calls from learnworld.

Here is the code for `webhoobhook_server.py`:

```py
import csv
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import json
import hashlib
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

EXPECTED_SIGNATURE = "{expected signiture, cut this out}"

CSV_FILE_PATH = "userData.csv"  # Path to the CSV file

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.INFO)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json()
    
    # Verify the webhook signature
    signature = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(data).encode()).hexdigest()
    if signature != EXPECTED_SIGNATURE:
        abort(401)  # Return 401 Unauthorized status code if the signature does not match
    
    # Extract the webhook type
    webhook_type = data['type']
    
    if webhook_type == 'userUpdated':
        user_data = data['data']['user']
        user_id = user_data['id']
        
        # Search for matching ID in the CSV file
        csv_data = read_csv_file(CSV_FILE_PATH)
        matching_row = find_matching_row(csv_data, user_id)
        
        if matching_row:
            # Update existing line in CSV file
            updated_data = update_data(matching_row, user_data)
            write_csv_file(CSV_FILE_PATH, csv_data)
            logging.info(f"User data updated: {user_id}")
        else:
            # Append data to the end of the CSV file
            append_data_to_csv(CSV_FILE_PATH, user_data)
            logging.info(f"New user data appended: {user_id}")
    
    # Process or perform additional operations based on the webhook type
    
    # Return a response (optional)
    return 'Webhook received successfully'






def read_csv_file(file_path):
    """
    Read the contents of a CSV file and return the data as a list of dictionaries.
    """
    with open(file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        data = list(reader)
    return data


def find_matching_row(data, user_id):
    """
    Find and return the row in the CSV data with a matching user ID.
    """
    for row in data:
        if row['id'] == user_id:
            return row
    return None


def update_data(row, new_data):
    """
    Update the existing row in the CSV data with the new data.
    """
    row.update(new_data)
    return row


def write_csv_file(file_path, data):
    """
    Write the data to a CSV file.
    """
    fieldnames = data[0].keys() if data else []
    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)


def append_data_to_csv(file_path, new_data):
    """
    Append new data to the end of the CSV file.
    """
    with open(file_path, 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=new_data.keys())
        writer.writerow(new_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

My problem is that even though I can run `webhook_server.py` within the server, the CSV file doesn't get changed. In fact, I don't even know how to get to the python terminal to see any errors that get raised.
ChatGPT says that my python code checks out (as far as I trust it), but the code doesn't seem to do anything.

Another issue is that after running the program, I can't do anything else. I'm given the option to "Press CTR:+C to quit", but I can't look into the CSV file without killing the flask server.

How can I make this work?

Comment: How are you running runwebhook_server.py? Aren't you running from a terminal? If so, the output (if any) should show up there itself.

Comment: Try to use an absolute path to the CSV file because relative paths may not point to the expected location.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be running a server direct in your terminal at all in the first place. Set up a systemd service to run the server so it happens in the background and keeps running even after your client disconnects; you can read logs with `journalctl`. Arguably, this is a system administration question/problem, not a programming one, insofar as this is about good practices for running services on UNIXy systems and not really specific to what the service _is_.

Comment: `write_csv_file(CSV_FILE_PATH, csv_data)` Is that just writing the input to the output file instead of writing the updated_data to the output file?

Answer (score 0):

First you have create services for your program in etc/systemd/system/your_service_name.service

Then write script for your code in your_service_name.service

The code would like bellows

```
[Unit]
Description=test demo service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=centos
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ python /path/to/your_code.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now just run systemctl start your_service_name on your terminal

For log you can create new log file in your code.

Comment: One might need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to look for new configuration files. It'd also be a good idea to advise `systemctl enable your_service_name` before `systemctl start your-service-name` so it's restarted on boot.

Answer (score 0):

you can run your flask application for development using a virtual environment  and gunicorn with nginx port forwarding. I'll put an example with supervisorctl.

example NGINX configuriation(/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{your app} - don't forget to delete default first)

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/adflaunt.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/adflaunt.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = adflaunt.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name adflaunt.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Example supervisor config(/etc/supervisor/conf.d/adflaunt.conf):

```
[program:yourprogram]
command= /home/yourusername/yourfolder/env/bin/gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 app:app
directory=/home/yourusername/yourfolder
autostart=true
autorestart=true
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
stdout_logfile=/home/yourusername/out.log
stderr_logfile=/home/yourusername/err.log
```

Note: this configuration is allowing you to use socket.io if you need.
Note:you need to create a virtual environment.

You can find a simple youtube tutorial here:https://yewtu.be/watch?v=LUFn-QVcmB8